# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable using fpgrowth algorithm with mlxtend

Tags: python, data-mining, mlxtend

from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import fpgrowth
#use F-P growth algorithm

#Num

frequent_itemsets_fp_num=fpgrowth(num, min_support=0.01, use_colnames=True)

Hi,
I've tried to use fpgrowth with mlxtend but have an error 'module' object not callable. I've tried to use 'pip install git+git://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend.git', it doesn't neither.
Could i have any recommendations to sort this out please.

Tks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the installed version on your machine. And install the newest version.

```
pip uninstall mlxtend
pip install git+git://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend.git
```